# How to go about solving pairwise disjoint proof with collections of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let A, B be two pairwise disjoint families of sets. let D=AUB. 
Prove if Union over A and Union over B are disjoint, the D is pairwise disjoint. 
I started the proof and split it into three cases. Well I'm having issues picking a third case. 
I have

Let X,Y be in D=AUB

Need to show: X=Y or X interest Y= empty set

Case 1: X,Y in A

Case 2: X,Y in B

Case 3: I'm confused as how to set up. I want to do it with cases as I understand it better this way. Any help as to how to continue is appreciated! I have X in A and Y in B but then I realized I'm just going a step back.

Comment: Any element $X \in A$ is a subset of the union over $A$, and any element $Y \in B$ is a subset of the union over $B$.  So if the two unions are disjoint then $x \in X \in A$ is an element of the union over $A$ and so not an element of the union over $B$ and so  $x \not \in Y \in B$

Comment: If $u \in X \cap Y$, then $u \in X$ and $u \in Y$. So $u$ in union over $A$ and $u$ in union over $B$ ...

Comment: @Henry    I'm confused as to how I would incorporate this for my third case. I know the to prove the other two as those are basically in my assumption. But for the third case I am not sure where to place X and Y

Comment: @StevenGregory is u an element? So then for my third case do I bring in the union portion of my assumptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle (u \in X) \wedge (X \in A) \implies u \in \bigcup_{S \in A}S$. Similarly 
$\displaystyle (u \in Y) \wedge (Y \in B) \implies u \in \bigcup_{S \in B}S$.
 Since we assumed these unions were disjoint, we have a contradiction. Hence  $X, Y \in D$ must also be disjoint.